# size_t or int for dimensions, index, etc

Tags: c#, c++, array

In C++, `size_t` (or, more correctly `T::size_type` which is "usually" `size_t`; i.e., a `unsigned` type) is used as the return value for `size()`, the argument to `operator[]`, etc. (see [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), et. al.)

On the other hand, .NET languages use `int` (and, optionally, `long`) for the same purpose; in fact, CLS-compliant languages are [not required to support unsigned types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3(v=vs.110).aspx#Types).

Given that .NET is newer than C++, something tells me that there may be [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275150/advice-on-unsigned-int-gangnam-style-edition) using `unsigned int` even for things that "can't possibly" be negative like an array index or length.  Is the C++ approach "historical artifact" for backwards compatibility?  Or are there real and significant design tradeoffs between the two approaches?

Why does this matter?  Well ... what should I use for a new multi-dimensional class in C++; `size_t` or `int`?

```
struct Foo final // e.g., image, matrix, etc.
{
    typedef int32_t /* or int64_t*/ dimension_type; // *OR* always "size_t" ?
    typedef size_t size_type; // c.f., std::vector<>

    dimension_type bar_; // maybe rows, or x
    dimension_type baz_; // e.g., columns, or y

    size_type size() const { ... } // STL-like interface
};
```

Comment: Worth noting: in several places in the .NET Framework, `-1` is returned from functions that return an index, to indicate "not found" or "out of range."  It's also returned from `Compare()` functions (implementing `IComparable`).  A 32 bit int is considered the go to type for a general number, for what I hope are obvious reasons.

Comment: Related: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97541/what-are-the-best-practices-regarding-unsigned-ints | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795453/why-prefer-signed-over-unsigned-in-c

Comment: C++ STL is wrong. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Puio5dly9N8#t=1h2m50s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Given that .NET is newer than C++, something tells me that there may be problems using unsigned int even for things that "can't possibly" be negative like an array index or length.

Yes. For certain types of applications such as image processing or array processing, it is often necessary to access elements relative to the current position:

```
sum = data[k - 2] + data[k - 1] + data[k] + data[k + 1] + ...
```

In these types of applications, you cannot perform range check with unsigned integers without thinking carefully:

```
if (k - 2 < 0) {
    throw std::out_of_range("will never be thrown"); 
}

if (k < 2) {
    throw std::out_of_range("will be thrown"); 
}

if (k < 2uL) {
    throw std::out_of_range("will be thrown, without signedness ambiguity"); 
}
```

Instead you have to ***rearrange*** your range check expression. That is the main difference. Programmers must also remember the integer conversion rules. When in doubt, re-read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions

A lot of applications do not need to use very large array indices, but they do need to perform range checks. Furthermore, a lot of programmers are not trained to do this expression rearrangement gymnastics. A single missed opportunity opens the door to an exploit.

C# is indeed designed for those applications that will not need more than 2^31 elements per array. For example, a spreadsheet application does not need to deal with that many rows, columns, or cells. C# deals with the upper limit by having [optional checked arithmetic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) that can be enabled for a block of code with a keyword without messing with compiler options. For this reason, C# favors the use of signed integer. When these decisions are considered altogether, it makes good sense.

C++ is simply different, and is harder to get correct code.

Regarding the practical importance of allowing signed arithmetic to remove a potential violation of "principle of least astonishment", a case in point is OpenCV, which uses signed 32-bit integer for matrix element index, array size, pixel channel count, etc. Image processing is an example of programming domain that uses relative array index heavily. Unsigned integer underflow (negative result wrapped around) will severely complicate algorithm implementation.

Comment: @Dan: if you need to cite something, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395205/why-are-unsigned-integers-error-prone) would be better.

Comment: @Dan: John Regehr is actively researching this issue in programming languages. See http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1401

Comment: There are contrarian opinions: https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/a-praise-of-size_t-and-other-unsigned-types/

Answer (score 14):

This answer truly depends on who is going to use your code, and what standards they want to see.

`size_t` is an integer size with a purpose:

> The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.  (C++11 specification 18.2.6)

Thus, any time you wish to work with the size of objects in bytes, you *should* use `size_t`.  Now in many cases, you're not using these dimensions/indexes to count bytes, but most developers choose to use `size_t` there for consistency.

**Note that you should *always* use `size_t` if your class is intended to have the look and feel of a STL class.  All of the STL classes in the specification use `size_t`.**  It is valid for the compiler to typedef `size_t` to be `unsigned int`, and it's also valid for it to be typedefed to `unsigned long`.  If you use `int` or `long` directly, you'll eventually run into compilers where a person who thinks your class followed the STL's style gets trapped because you didn't follow the standard.

As for using signed types, there's a few advantages:

- Shorter names -- it's really easy for people to type `int`, but much harder to clutter the code with `unsigned int`.
- One integer for each size -- There is only one CLS compliant integer of 32-bits, which is Int32.  In C++, there's two (`int32_t` and `uint32_t`).  This can make API interoperability simpler

The big disadvantage of signed types is the obvious one: you lose half of your domain.  A signed number cannot count as high as an unsigned number.  When C/C++ came around, this was very important.  One needed to be able to address the full capability of the processor, and to do that you needed to use unsigned numbers.

For the kinds of applications .NET targeted, there was not as strong of a need for a full-domain unsigned index.  Many of the purposes for such numbers are simply invalid in a managed language (memory pooling comes to mind).  Also, as .NET came out, 64-bit computers were clearly the future.  We're a long way away from needing the full range of a 64-bit integer, so sacrificing one bit is not as painful as it was before.  If you really need 4 billion indexes, you simply switch to using 64-bit integers.  At worst, you run it on a 32 bit machine and it's a little slow.

I view the trade as one of convenience.  If you happen to have enough computing power that you don't mind wasting a bit of your index type that you will never-ever-ever use, then it's convenient to just type `int` or `long` and walk away from it.  If you find you really wanted that last bit, then you probably should have paid attention to the signedness of your numbers.

Comment: @Dan You can construct cases like that where having unsigned ints would matter, and in those cases its best to use the full language features to resolve it.  However, I must say that it would be an interesting construction to have a class where `bar_ * baz_` can overflow a signed integer but not an unsigned integer.  Limiting ourselves to C++, it's worth noting that unsigned overflow is defined in the spec, but signed overflow is undefined behavior, so if the modulo arithmetic of unsigned integers is desirable, definitely use them, because its actually defined!

Comment: @Dan - *if* the `size()` overflowed the *signed* multiplication, you're in language UB land. (and in `fwrapv` mode, see next:) *When then*, with just a tiny wee bit more, it overflowed the *unsigned* multiplication, you in user-code-bug land - you would return a bogus size. So I don't think unsigned buys much here.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [answer of rwong above](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/338107/6559) already excellently highlights the issues.

I'll add my 002:

- [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), that is, a size that ...

  > can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).

  ... is only required for range indices when `sizeof(type)==1`, that is, if you're dealing with byte (`char`) types. (But, we note, [it can be smaller than a ptr type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-uintptr-t):
- As such, `xxx::size_type` could be used in 99.9% cases even if it were a signed sized type. (compare [`ssize_t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Primitives.html))
- The fact that `std::vector` and friends chose `size_t`, an **unsigned** type, for the size and indexing is [considered by some](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvtFGa6XJDU) to be a design flaw. I concur. (Seriously, take 5 minutes and watch the [lightning talk CppCon 2016: Jon Kalb “unsigned: A Guideline for Better Code"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvtFGa6XJDU).)
- When you design an C++ API today, you're in a tight place: Use `size_t` to be consistent with the Standard Library, or use (a *signed*)  **`intptr_t`** or `ssize_t` for easy and less bug prone indexing calculations.
- Don't use int32 or int64 - use `intptr_t` if you want to go signed, and want machine word size, or use `ssize_t`.

To directly answer the question, it is not entirely an "historical artefact", as the theoretical issue of needing to address more than half the ("indexing", or) address space *must* be, aehm, addressed somehow in a low level language like C++.

In hindsight, I, *personally*, think, it **is** a design flaw that the Standard Library uses unsigned `size_t` all over the place even where it does not represent a raw memory size, but a capacity of typed data, like for the collections:

- *given C++s integer promotion rules* ->
- unsigned types just don't make good candidates for "semantic" types for something like a size that is semantically unsigned.

I'll repeat [Jon's advice](https://youtu.be/wvtFGa6XJDU?t=358) here:

- Select types for the operations they support (not the range of values). (*1)
- Don't use unsigned types in you API. This hides bugs with no upside benefit.
- Don't use "unsigned" for quantities.(*2)

(*1) i.e. unsigned == bitmask, never do math on it (here hits the first exception - you may need a counter that wraps - this must be an unsigned type.)

(*2) quantities meaning something you count and/or do math on.

Comment: What do you mean with "full avilable flat memory"? Also, sure you don't want `ssize_t`, defined as the signed pendant to `size_t` instead of `intptr_t`, which can store any (non-member-)pointer and might thus be bigger?

Comment: @Deduplicator - Well I guess I may have gotten the `size_t` definition slightly messed up. See [size_t vs. intptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-uintptr-t) and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t 
 Learned something new today. :-) I think the rest of the arguments stand, I'll see if I can fix the types used.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add that for performance reasons I normally use size_t, to *ensure* that miscalculations cause an underflow which means both range checks (below zero and above size()) can be reduced to one:

using signed int:

```
int32_t i = GetRandomNumberFromRange(-1000, 1000);

if (i < 0)
{
    //error
}

if (i > size())
{
    //error
}
```

using unsigned int:

```
int32_t i = GetRandomNumberFromRange(-1000, 1000);

/// This will underflow any number below zero, so that it becomes a very big *positive* number instead.
uint32_t asUnsigned = static_cast<uint32_t>(i);

/// We now don't need to check for below zero, since an unsigned integer can only be positive.
if (asUnsigned > size())
{
    //error
}
```

Comment: You *really* want to explain that one more thoroughly.

Comment: To make the answer more useful, perhaps you can describe how the integer array bounds or offset comparison (signed and unsigned) looks like in the machine code from various compiler vendors. There are many online C++ compilers and disassembly sites that can show the corresponding compiled machine code for the given C++ code and compiler flags.

Comment: I tried to explain this some more.